# angularjs 500 internal error

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, servlets

I am writing a simple **angularjs - J2EE** application to fetch data from **mysql server** and display on the html page.
I am calling the angular function on form submit as:

```
<div id="register_form" ng-controller="MyDiaryLogin">
        <form>
            <ul>
                <li><input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="user.firstname" /></li>
                <li><input type="text" name="lastname" ng-model="user.lastname" /></li>
                <li><input type="text" name="email" ng-model="user.email" /></li>
                <li><input type="password" name="password" ng-model="user.password" /></li>
                <li><input type="password" name="confpass" ng-model="user.confpass" /></li>
                <li><input type="text" name="age" ng-model="user.age" /></li>
                <li><input type="text" name="occupation" ng-model="user.occupation" /></li>
                <li><input type="button" name="register" ng-click="register()" value="REGISTER" /></li>
            </ul>
        </form>
        <p><h2>{{status}}</h2></p>
    </div>
```

*{{status}}* here is $scope property from my angular script.js:

```
mydiary.controller('MyDiaryLogin', function($scope, $http){
$scope.user = {};
$scope.register = function(){
    $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'http://localhost:9091/Angular1/getData',
          header: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
          data: $scope.user
    }).success(function(data){
        $scope.status = data;
    });
};
```

I have written a servlet to get data from database but the error comes before reaching to the servlet as I am printing some text on console in servlet.
When I click on *REGISTER* button browser console shows an **error** as:

> **POST http://localhost:9091/Angular1/getData 500 (Internal Server Error)**

and this error points to `angular.js` lib at some `xhr.send(...)` function:

```
if (responseType) {
    try {
      xhr.responseType = responseType;
    } catch (e) {
      // WebKit added support for the json responseType value on 09/03/2013
      // https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=73648. Versions of Safari prior to 7 are
      // known to throw when setting the value "json" as the response type. Other older
      // browsers implementing the responseType
      //
      // The json response type can be ignored if not supported, because JSON payloads are
      // parsed on the client-side regardless.
      if (responseType !== 'json') {
        throw e;
      }
    }
  }

  xhr.send(post || null);
}
```

For your reference my **servlet class's doPost method**:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException{
    try{
        System.out.println("CALLING THE METHOD");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydiary","root","");

        String query = "SELECT * FROM users";
        pstmt = cn.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

        String json = new Gson().toJson(rs);
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        out = response.getWriter();
        out.write(json);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{
        try{}
        finally{
            if(rs!=null)
                rs.close();
            if(pstmt!=null)
                pstmt.close();
            if(out!=null)
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            if(cn!=null)
                cn.close();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e1){
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Please help me find the root of the problem and is there anything wrong with the complete application code I have written? I am not sure about **how to use angular to display data/ return json format data from servlet?**

Comment: your doPost method looks really ugly... please implement correctly the try/catch clause!

Comment: Looks like something is blowing up on your server before the postMethod get called. is the class of your doPost method even being instantiated? The problem doesn't seem to be on your angular code.

Comment: @Juan: Yes I am compiling my class successfully. There doesn't seem to be any error with it.

Comment: Not compiling. Instantiating. Can you debug the server? If not try adding logging on the class constructor and seeing if that is even being called.

Comment: I created the constructor and displayed some text in it but it is not being called...and same error

Comment: Look at your servlet container and your web.xml configuration. Something might be wrong there. Your Servlet is not involved in this.

Comment: I think you're not supposed to close the `PrintWriter` (variable `out` in your case), because the servlet container will do that for you.

Comment: @jabu.10245: I did as you suggest. But still the same error

Comment: @GuenterGuckelsberger: There is no xml involved. I have written WebServlet annotation for my servlet.

Comment: Ok well I got it working. There was something wrong with my servlet class. I replaced doPost method with other servlet class and its working. Now how do I display the data being retrieved in ResultSet? as $scope.status property is displaying nothing on my html page?

Comment: Are you sure, your servlet returns non empty data? May be your resultset is empty. I am asking this, because your angular code seems to be ok.

Comment: Yes I am sure. ResultSet contains desired data. Will toJson() method work for ResultSet without calling next() over resultset?

Comment: Obviously not. Didn't know Gson before, but had a short look at the Api. There is now toJson(rs:ResultSet) look here: http://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/

Comment: ok...well I tried instantiating class and here is the error: a loop of some error at com.google.gson.getAdapter.. You know what it might be related to? the cmd buffer gets full so can't tell the very first error message.

Answer (score 0):

To give you an idea of how you could convert a resultset into JSON, I added this class here. You use it like: jsonArr = ResultSetConverter.convert(result,"");

This is a very general class that can handle all sql data types, so pick what you need.

```js
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONException;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class ResultSetConverter {
  public static final Calendar tzUTC = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));    

  public static JSONArray convert( ResultSet rs, String freitextlabel )
    throws SQLException, JSONException
  {
    JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
   
    while(rs.next()) {
      int numColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
      JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

      for (int i=1; i<numColumns+1; i++) {
        String column_name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);

        if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.ARRAY){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getArray(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.BIGINT){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getInt(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.BOOLEAN){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getBoolean(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.BLOB){
            obj.put(column_name, rs.getBlob(column_name));
           }
           else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.DOUBLE){
            obj.put(column_name, rs.getDouble(column_name)); 
           }
           else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.FLOAT){
            obj.put(column_name, rs.getFloat(column_name));
           }
           else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.INTEGER){
            obj.put(column_name, rs.getInt(column_name));
           }
           else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR){
            obj.put(column_name, rs.getNString(column_name));
           }
           else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.VARCHAR){
            if (freitextlabel.length()>0 && column_name.equalsIgnoreCase("freitext"))
             obj.put(freitextlabel, rs.getString(column_name));
            else
             obj.put(column_name, rs.getString(column_name));
           }
           else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.TINYINT){
            obj.put(column_name, rs.getInt(column_name));
           }
           else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.SMALLINT){
            obj.put(column_name, rs.getInt(column_name));
           }
           else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.DATE){
            obj.put(column_name.concat("_js"), rs.getDate(column_name));
           }
           else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP){
           //obj.put(column_name.concat("_js"), rs.getTimestamp(column_name,tzUTC));  
            Timestamp ts = rs.getTimestamp(column_name,tzUTC);
           // obj.put (column_name, ts !=null ? new Date(ts.getTime)  : null); 
            obj.put(column_name.concat("_js"), ts != null ? new Date(ts.getTime()) : null);
           }
           else{
            obj.put(column_name, rs.getObject(column_name));
           }
         }

         json.put(obj);
       }

       return json;
     }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for finally coming out with help Guenter. I'll keep looking for some other way of conversion but this really solved the issue :)